# Why do I see 2 IP addresses in the "fwd" info when looking at Heroku logs?

Tags: heroku

I currently have a PHP application on Heroku and i've been learning all the different features.  Recently, I started to monitor the logs of my application and I am confused about one thing.

I am seeing 2 IP addresses separated by a comma in the "fwd" information while tailing the log.

Could someone explain what could cause this?  I am using Cloudflare as a CDN.